# What would happen to a quark if it could be isolated, into what particles it would change?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, quarks, confinement

[WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge#What_is_the_quantum_of_charge?) defines as **quantum charge** the $-\frac{1}{3} e$ charge value of the down quark and as **elementary charge** the *-1e* of the electron. The elementary quark particle cannot be isolated in the lab and its charge is not an *elementary* charge therefore it is a combinatoric fractional charge due its interaction mainly with virtual charged particles inside the *"quark soup"* of the proton or the neutron it is confined. Therefore, the fractal charge of a quark cannot exist in an non-isolated, free condition.

Thus, if ever a single quark could be released and isolated **(i.e. knocked out from the nucleus)** in the lab it should instantly change to other particles.

My question is, are there any theoretical predictions of what would happen in this hypothetical scenario into what particles the quark would decay? Any Feynman diagrams?

Comment: I'm not sure why your question got closed, but I think your answer is [hadronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadronization).

Comment: At the current understanding there is nothing prohibiting "fractional" charges. The currently defined elementary charge is called so not because we proved that it's elementary. It could be that the true elementary charge is 1/300. As far as we know the quarks are not free not because of their fractional charges but because of the independent strong interaction that grows with a distance.

Comment: @OON Interesting argument specially the last sentence of your comment. Of course one could disagree by asking, why is then no elementary free particle in nature with a fractal charge ever observed?